# Why does SPI flash has HOLD# pin, as opposed to stopping the clock?

Tags: spi, flash

A SPI flash like Micron M25P16 (shown below) has a HOLD# pin, and any input data is ignored if HOLD# is asserted at a rising clock edge.

[image]

But can't the clock just be stopped instead ?

Comment: Gating a clock is usually a bad idea, because it's difficult to do properly: if you do it asynchronously, you run the risk of getting runt clock pulses.

Comment: Good point, and I see that makes sense for designs where the SPI clock is actually a clock, and not generated as a "data" signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HOLD#` signal for use in an SPI bus with multiple slaves.  Stopping `CLK` will stop the whole bus, while asserting `HOLD#` will only stop transactions to that specific SPI slave.  `HOLD#` is slave specific like `CS#` is.

Imagine you have a flash on the SPI bus, but also a SPI sensor that you need to read at a specific time.  Now while you are in a transaction with the SPI flash, the time comes to read the sensor.  You could just finish the transaction with the SPI flash, but then you compromise the timing of the sensor reading.  If you stop the clock, you cannot read the sensor either.  But if you assert `HOLD#` to the flash, you can now start a second SPI transaction to the sensor.  Once you are done with the sensor, you deassert `HOLD#`, and you continue with your SPI flash transaction.